# Actionscript 3. Display alternative images (using conditionals) when mp3 available or not-available to play

Tags: image, actionscript-3, audio, conditional-statements

I wondering the best way to handle this

I'm successfully loading sounds (audioMP3) from an XML file and handling the IO errors with EventListener.

I would like to have an image show on stage, when an MP3 is available or an alternative image when there is no MP3.

I've been trying to access the IO error and use it in conditionals to select the image e.g.
If there is an IO error then display btnAudioNo
Else display btnAudioYes

Here's the eventListemer:

```
audioMP3.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onSoundIOError, false, 0, true);
function onSoundIOError (e:IOErrorEvent){
    trace(e.text);
    removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onSoundIOError)
}
```

And my dodgy conditional attempt:

```
var btnAudioYes:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new(getDefinitionByName("btnAudioYes")) (0,0) );
var btnAudioNo:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new(getDefinitionByName("btnAudioNo")) (0,0) );
if(ioError = false){
    addChild(btnAudioYes);
}
else {
    addChild(btnAudioNo);
}
```

My questions are, how can I get this to work and is there a better way to determine if there is an MP3 file available (in the XML file) and display the appropriate image?

Many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  Please accept an answer, or update your question if not

Answer (score 1):

Listener (in addition to the IOErrorEvent) to the ProgressEvent, if you get progress then the file exists and you can cancel (close) the loader.  Unless you want the entire audio file loaded at this point, then listen for the complete event instead.

```
loader:Loader = new Loader();

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onSoundProgress, false, 0, true);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoadComplete); //use this only if you want to load the entire audio file at this point
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onSoundIOError, false, 0, true);

loader.load("your file");

function onSoundIOError (e:IOErrorEvent){
    //this function will only run if the file does not exist
    loader = null;
    var btnAudioNo:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new(getDefinitionByName("btnAudioNo")) (0, 0) );
    addChild(btnAudioNo);
}

function onSoundProgress(e:ProgressEvent) {
    //this function will only run if the file DOES exist

    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onSoundProgress); //we don't want this firing again

    var btnAudioYes:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new(getDefinitionByName("btnAudioYes")) (0,0) );
    addChild(btnAudioYes);

    //if you you don't want to actually load the audio file, do this to cancel the load
    loader.close(); //close the loader to keep from loading the rest of the file
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.unloadAndStop(true);
    loader = null;
}

//use this only if you want to load the entire audio file at this point
function onSoundComplete(e:Event):void {
    //do whatever you need to do with the sound...
}
```

Comment: A note on this: the `onSoundProgress` method will be called every frame so, it's not a good place to create things (new-up objects).

Comment: yea, in theory the loader.close() will keep it from being fired more than once, but I've never tested that, so I updated it to remove the listener

Comment: Sorry... I didn't noticed the `loader.close();`. But I'm not sure of it too. Never tried to call close on the progress event, but it sould work.